# Are groups in Illustrator included to "items on page"

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I need to perform via applescript some action on all items inside the Illustrator document apart of groups.

When I set my counter as

"repeat with i from (count page items of current document) to 1 by -1"

should I subtract the number of groups inside the document?

In other words are groups included in "page items"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the question via simple script:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    set numberOfItems to (count page items in current document)
    display dialog numberOfItems

end tell
```

When I have 3 shapes the numberOfItems is 3, but when I group two of them (OR all of them in one group), then the numberOfItems is 4.

Thus, groups are different items and should be counted/treated appropriately...